# Using a class to include / require a file

Tags: php, function, class, require

I'm using the following code almost everytime that I require a file:

```
$file = 'my_file.php';
if (!file_exists ($file)) {
    sessionLog(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).">Class NOT found: ".$file);
}else{
    require ($file);
    sessionLog(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).">Class Loaded: ".$file);
}
```

Is there a practical way to create a class or function to avoid re-writing the code every time I require a file?

```
// Function to validate and include file

include_this_file(my_file.php)
```

Comment: its called autoloading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard nowadays it to use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to manage most (if not all) of the file, class and functions.

Projects using composer benefit from it's PSR-compatible implementation of [autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading), but you can also implement your own and register it with the PHP interpreter.